# How to store data from Kafka to Redis using two different streams with different topics in pyspark streaming application?

Tags: apache-spark, redis, apache-kafka, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a pyspark application which configures 2 data streams:

**Data flow A)** Read from kafka (topics 1 and 2) -> merge the topics DStreams -> do stuff -> output to REDIS.

**Data flow B)** Read from kafka (topics 3, 4 and 5) -> merge the topics DStreams -> do stuff -> output to same REDIS.

I can get data inside REDIS only when one of them are configured, but not both.

Actually, this happens even if I change REDIS output to pprint. I only get output printed if only one the two flows are active.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the number of execution threads available.

Spark documentation says each receiver uses a dedicated thread to get data in. I was running this application in local mode with master url as "local[*]", what gives me 4 threads as my PC has 4 cores.

As my application configures 5 different kafka topics to read from I need at least 6 threads (5+1 for the driver program) to get my program running. As I have only 4, and the DStreams are merged downstream the computation never starts.

Solution: `MASTER_URL = local[10]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to join 2 Dstream i mean first stream points to topicA which returns (K,V) and second DStream monitors topicB which returns (K,V1). If yes then you can join 2 DStream using join() method which would return (K (V,V1)).

Or you want to pass TopicA, TopicB while creating stream (KafkaUtils.createStream()) and then insert (K,V) followed by  (K,V1) into Redis ?